# How to set permissions in Linux /var/www to allow automatic overwrite from PHP-Apache

Tags: php, linux, apache, permissions

I would like to allow users to upload new versions of documents via a web app. However, the permissions are not currently set up to allow any file within the particular folder to be overwritten by default. Is there a way to set up the default permissions or other settings of all current and future files to automatically be replaced by a new file with an identical name, and path obviously.

Edit: I am obviously not referring to the entire www folder! Just a subfolder :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question, you just need to make sure that the Apache user (usually named **apache** or **nobody**) has write permission to the directories.  For example, `chgrp -R apache /var/www/userdir && chmod -R 0775 /var/www/userdir`

However, if this server is publicly accessible, it's a very bad idea to do this.  Instead, you'll want to look into something like [suPHP](http://www.suphp.org/), which allows Apache to run as the user and will allow user-uploaded files to be overwritten.